# How do I find all possible permutations for a specific number?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get something to work like this:
`function permutations(sumWorkingFor, [numbersAllowed, numbersAllowed]) {}`
e.g for `permutations(5, [1,2])` it would give:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 2
1, 1, 2, 1
1, 2, 1, 1
2, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
2, 1, 2
1, 2, 2
```

Comment: What is `allowed` good for?

Comment: Is `1, 1, 1, 1, 1` valid?

Comment: yes ```1, 1, 1, 1, 1``` is allowed

Answer (score 1):

A very good usecase for generators:

```
  function* sum(target, numbers, previous = []) {
    if(target === 0) yield previous;
    if(target <= 0) return;
    for(const n of numbers) 
       yield* sum(target - n, numbers, [...previous, n]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely more exhaustive than it needs to be, but here is the logic:

1. Extend the array so we can take permutations (i.e., turn [1, 2] into [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2] since there are maximum 5 1's and 2 2's to make 5.)
2. Get all combinations of this *extended* array.
3. Filter out the combinations that do not sum up to `sumWorkingFor`
4. Get all permutations of the remaining combinations
5. Filter out the duplicates <sup>(uses `toString` as a hacky way to index the array, but there is definitely a cleaner solution)</sup>

```js
function permutations(sumWorkingFor, numbers) {
    let modifiedNumbers = [];
    numbers.forEach((i)=>{modifiedNumbers = modifiedNumbers.concat(Array(Math.floor(sumWorkingFor/i)).fill(i))});
    let perm = (xs) => {
      let ret = [];
    
      for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i = i + 1) {
        let rest = perm(xs.slice(0, i).concat(xs.slice(i + 1)));
    
        if(!rest.length) {
          ret.push([xs[i]])
        } else {
          for(let j = 0; j < rest.length; j = j + 1) {
            ret.push([xs[i]].concat(rest[j]))
          }
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }
    let combine = function(a) {
      let fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
        if (n == 0) {
          if (got.length > 0) {
            all[all.length] = got;
          }
          return;
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
          fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
        }
        return;
      }
      let all = [];
      for (let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        fn(i, a, [], all);
      }
      all.push(a);
      return all;
    }
    let sum = (i) => {return i.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)};
    let findIndex = (a, i) => {
        for(let j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
            if(a[j].toString() == i.toString()){
                return j;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    let allPerms = combine(modifiedNumbers).filter((i)=>sum(i) === sumWorkingFor);
    let unique = [];
    allPerms.filter((i, a) => findIndex(allPerms, i) === a).forEach((i)=>{
      unique = unique.concat(perm(i))
    });
    return [... new Set(unique.map((i)=>i.toString()))].map((i)=>i.split(",").map((j)=>parseInt(j)));
}

console.log(permutations(10, [1, 2]));
```